# How can I drag left to right while Row is changing but Column is the same (for Excel)

Tags: excel, formula, distance

I am required to calculate this distance between many different points with latitude and longitude (e.g., Point 1 to Point 2, ... Point 1 to 1000, ... Point 999 to 1000)

I have a formula:

```
"=6371*ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-Information!$C$2))*COS(RADIANS(90-Information!C2))+SIN(RADIANS(90-Information!$C$2))*SIN(RADIANS(90-Information!C2))*COS(RADIANS(Information!$D$2-Information!D2)))*1000"
```

I would need to drag it from left to right and top to bottom. From top to bottom, the formula runs fine, but from left to right, I would need "Information!C2" to become "Information!C3" instead of "Information!D2", how am I able to do so? Thanks in advance!

The rationale for doing this is so that I need not change the formula manually for the thousands of line that I have.

I try to put $C2 instead but while dragging from left to right, the $C2 will not become $C3.
Have tried Index too but am not too sure how it works and kept facing error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to lay the results of a formula onto the columns when the key source cells are laid onto the rows. It would be helpful if you provide some sample data as they are in your file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Offset(ref, row, col)` to add the column as offset to the row

```
=OFFSET(Information!$C$2,COLUMN() - x, 0)
```

where you need to adjust the x in accordance to which leftmost column the formula is in